# How to update class field?

Tags: class, flutter, dart, field

I'm working with Flutter (dart) language and I have my user's model. I'm trying to update a field of the user's model but it's not working. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```dart
class User {
   String nickname = "potatoes"; // NOT final

   User() {
       // Doing some stuff 
   }


   updateNickname(newNickname) {
      print("NICKNAME VALUE BEFORE UPDATE $this.nickname"); // Shows potatoes
      this.nickname = newNickname;
      print("NICKNAME VALUE AFTER UPDATE $this.nickname"); // Shows potatoes

   }

}
```

I can't understand why it's not updating, could someone explain to me how should I do it? I'm not working with getters and setters because I don't need to, but maybe I should?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, nickname is changing but print code is wrong, `$this.nickname` this should be `${this.nickname}`

Comment: Thanks, that was it, my bad. Any idea why in my future builder the value snapshot.data does not get updated? As "future:" I'm "doing this _userModel.getUserNickname();", at first it's perfectly loaded but when I'm updating the nickname value nothing happens. Any idea why?

Comment: Because this modal cannot be listened. I dont know what u want exactly but u can look `ChangeNotifier`